# How to click an option in div using selenium (python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, click

I tried to build a web scraper using selenium, and I was stuck at a window popped out that asked me to choose the option of city. Here's the html:

[image]

I tried to click the option of "New York". So,I tried to use

```
city = find_element_by_id("area-box-body")
city.select_by_value('New York')
```

But, it wouldn't work. Is there any solution for it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the box and then click the value with the value.

```
box = driver.find_element_by_id("area-select-box")
box.click()
value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='area-box-body']//dd[.='New York']")
value.click()
```

Comment: When I ran the code u provided, it showed "element is not attached to the page document". So, I tried to ignore "open up the box", which is the first two rows of the code.  Just clicked it based on the value, and it worked.  Is it necessary to open up the box?

Comment: Wasn't sure if the values were open etc. It depends on how it's displayed.

Comment: Cuz when the code ran into the "box.click()", it seems like it clicked the center part of the box, which is one of the option of city.